# Getting data from rss and adding it to a mysql db

Tags: php, rss, feed

Hi i am making a arcade site, and it would be nice if you could use a gamefeed.

ived tryed all day to get data from xml files and add it to my mysql db, but i cant get it working.

This is the xml file i want to get info from:

http://www.freegamesforyourwebsite.com/feeds.php?feed=latest-games&format=rss

and the i want to put it into my db

can you please help me :-)?

i tryed this:

```
<?php
$feedUrl = 'http://playtomic.com/games/feed/playtomic?format=xml';
$ret = array();

// retrieve search results 
if($xml = simplexml_load_file($feedUrl)) {          
    $result["item"] = $xml->xpath("/rss/channel/item"); 

    foreach($result as $key => $attribute) { 
        $i=0; 
        foreach($attribute as $element) { 
             $ret[$i]['title'] = (string)$element->title; 
             $ret[$i]['swf'] = (string)$element->SWF; 
             $i++; 
        } 
    } 
}  

echo "<pre>";
print_r($ret); 
?>
```

Comment: Sure, just show us what you have done and we will see why is it not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from http://www.softarea51.com/tutorials/parse_rss_with_php.html

you can always fetch the rss to an php array and do anything you want e.g. save it into a mysql db:

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('http://www.freegamesforyourwebsite.com/feeds.php?feed=latest-games&format=rss');
$arrFeeds = array();
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('entry') as $node) {
    $itemRSS = array ( 
  'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
  'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('summary')->item(0)->nodeValue,
  'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
  'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('published')->item(0)->nodeValue
  );
  array_push($arrFeeds, $itemRSS);
}


$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `rssitems` (`title`, `summary`, `link`, `published`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $title, $summary, $link, $published);

foreach( $arrFeeds as $RssItem){
    $title = $RssItem["title"];
    $summary = $RssItem["summary"];
    $link = $RssItem["link"];
    $published = $RssItem["published"];

    $stmt->execute();
}

$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();


?>
```

Comment: check it now. it now works. changed `item` to `entry` in line 6

Comment: okay fixed also the "date" and "summary" elements. now it run without any warning

Comment: if you want to see the content of an array you've got to use `var_dump` like this: `var_dump($arrFeeds);`

Comment: Wow ty! it worked :D!
- could it be to much to ask for some help with adding it to the db :-)??

Comment: OK. here you go with db code. you should have a `rssitems` table in db with corresponding columns and also don't for get to changed the db connection info in this line:

`$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');`

Comment: :) happy to hear that Patrick and don't forget to check the answer as the correct one.

Comment: Got a problem :/
Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object on line 26

Comment: `echo $mysqli->error` just BEFORE this line to see the mysql error:
`$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $title, $summary, $link, $published);`

Comment: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 &
Unknown column '' in 'field list'

Comment: hmmm... do you have the table with correct columns all of them should be `varchar`s

Comment: also you should have a auto-increment `id` column as primary key

Comment: Weird... it doesnt work if im doing it with this rss:

http://playtomic.com/games/feed/playtomic/v2?format=xml&category=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19&language=1&audience=0,1,2&ads=0&leaderboards=0&mtx=0&limit=20

Comment: it is normal this feed has another structure. if you to use this one you should use this code:

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('game') as $node) {
    $itemRSS = array ( 
  'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
  'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
  'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('play_url')->item(0)->nodeValue,
  'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('published')->item(0)->nodeValue
  );
  array_push($arrFeeds, $itemRSS);
}

Answer (score 0):

**This code is working perfectly fine for me ..**

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('http://www.hamarakhana.com/feed/');
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $item = array ( 
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            );
        array_push($feed, $item);
    }
    $limit = 10;
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
        $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
        $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
        echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
        echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
        echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
    }
```

*if you want to insert data into database ,
create your DB table and fields according to your requiremnt and run the insert query in for loop..*
[Click here to see the image of Rss Feeds Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEfBp.png)